# Weighted average of a dictionary - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following column in a data-frame (it is an example):

First row is: `'{"100":10,"50":3,"-90":2}'`.

Second row is: `'{"100":70,"50":3,"-90":2,"-40":3}'`.

I want to calculate a weighted average where the dictionary's keys are the values and the dictionary's values are the weights of the weighted average.

The final value of the first row should be: `64.666`, which is `(100*10+50*3-90*2)/(10+3+2)`; and the of the second row should be: `87.82`.

For each dictionary there might be hundreds of keys/values and the column might have thousands of rows. How can I code it efficiently? Preferably vectorially.

Comment: does the column contain a json string?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code so we can guide you to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).

```
import json

def cal_avg(dct):
    dct = json.loads(dct)
    return sum(int(k)*v for k,v in dct.items()) / sum(dct[k] for k in dct)

df['dct'].apply(cal_avg)
```

Output:

```
0    64.666667
1    87.820513
Name: dct, dtype: float64
```

Input DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dct': [
        '{"100":10,"50":3,"-90":2}',
        '{"100":70,"50":3,"-90":2,"-40":3}'
    ]
})
```

Comment: It gives me the following error: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not float`. Even if I put `str(dct)`.

Comment: @qwerty, what is the `type` of each `dct`, check this : `print(type(dct))`

Comment: Ahh, some of them are indeed float because they have a `nan` value... So I just added try and except

Comment: @qwerty, try this: `df['dct'].dropna().apply(cal_avg)`

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to grab all the keys and values, explode it into a different dataframe and then make the calculations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['{"100":10,"50":3,"-90":2}', '{"100":70,"50":3,"-90":2,"-40":3}']})

df2 = df.col1.str.findall('"(?P<key>-?\d*)":(?P<value>-?\d*)').to_frame()
df2 = df2.explode('col1')

df2[['value', 'weight']] = [(int(a), int(b)) for a,b in df2.col1.to_list()]
df2['prod'] = df2.value*df2.weight

df['weighted_avg'] = df2.groupby(level = 0)['prod'].sum() / df2.groupby(level = 0)['weight'].sum()
```

Comment: It's not missing a column; each dictionary might have a different length. Also, is there a way to convert the "dictionary" from strings to actual dictionaries?

Comment: Oh, it's all a single column, I see.

Answer (score 0):

try this easy for loop:

```
dataset = [{"100": 10, "50": 3, "-90": 2}, {"100": 70, "50": 3, "-90": 2, "-40": 3}]

for data in dataset:
    weighted_value = 0
    weight = 0
    for item in data.items():
        weighted_value += int(item[0]) * item[1]
        weight += item[1]
    weighted_average = weighted_value / weight
    print(weighted_average)
```

performance wise i dont think this can be optimized a lot further.